# System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, customsetting

I have a controller and I wrote a test class for it, the test class is giving me the error message I mentioned in the Title.
This is the controller:

```
public with sharing class OpenedAccountsController {

    public boolean ShowCloseLink {
    get;
        set;
    }

      public PageReference init() {

        PageReference redirectToPage = new PageReference('');

        redirectToPage = new PageReference(EnvironmentSettings.getOpenedAccountsUrl()) ;
        redirectToPage.getParameters().putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());

         redirectToPage.setRedirect(true);
         return redirectToPage;
    }
}
```

and this is the test class:

```
@isTest
public class OpenedAccountsTest {
    static testmethod void SandboxUrl() {
        Organization org;

        Test.startTest();

        PageReference pageRef = Page.OpenedAccounts;
        pageRef.getParameters().putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        OpenedAccountsController controller = new OpenedAccountsController();
        String nextPage;
        if (!String.isBlank(controller.init().getUrl()))
            nextPage = controller.init().getUrl(); // The error is here

        Test.stopTest();

        if (org.IsSandbox==True && !String.isBlank(nextPage))
        {
        //  System.debug('URL:'+ nextPage);

        }


    }
```

I know something is Null but I'm not sure what.

```
public class EnvironmentSettings {

    private static final External_Urls__c urlSetting =    External_Urls__c.getInstance();

    public static string getOpenedAccountsUrl() {
        return urlSetting.Opened_Accounts_Url__c;
    }

}
```

Comment: Surely you can tell us the line number... Likely `EnvironmentSettings.getOpenedAccountsUrl()` is returning null? Is it based on `Custom Setting` data?

Comment: Are you sure the error is on the line that you marked, and not the line above (where you pass the result of `getUrl()` to `String.isBlank()`?

Comment: Derek, you are right, it is on the line you mentioned.

@AdrianLarson This is the 'EnvironmentSettings' class:
'public class EnvironmentSettings {

    private static final External_Urls__c urlSetting =   External_Urls__c.getInstance();
public static string getOpenedAccountsUrl() {
        return urlSetting.Opened_Accounts_Url__c;
    }
}'
Does that help?

Comment: Can you [edit your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/148972/edit) to include the `EnvironmentSettings` class instead of putting it in a comment? Comments are limited in length and formatting, so it's rather hard to digest code placed in a comment.

Comment: Done! I entered the EnvironmentSettings, the EnvironmentSettingsTest class did not pass either:  I'm getting this error message: Class.sObjectCreator.createExternalUrls: line 396, column 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own data when you run `Unit Tests`. In this case, you must actually insert the `External_Urls__c` setting.

```
static testMethod void testExternalUrls()
{
    system.assertEquals(null, External_Urls__c.getInstance().Opened_Accounts_Url__c,
        'Data should not be populated before test setup');

    External_Urls__c instance = External_Urls__c.getInstance();
    instance.Opened_Accounts_Url__c='Populated';
    upsert instance;

    system.assertNotEquals(null, External_Urls__c.getInstance().Opened_Accounts_Url__c,
        'Data should be populated after test setup');
}
```

So, make sure you actually insert the custom setting before trying to run the rest of your test. This is a great use case for `@TestSetup`.

```
@TestSetup
static void setupCustomSetting()
{
    // insert custom setting here
}
```

Note from the `Apex Developer Guide`:

> ## [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling)
>
> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User
> - Profile
> - Organization
> - AsyncApexJob
> - CronTrigger
> - RecordType
> - ApexClass
> - ApexTrigger
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage

Comment: But not having a Hierarchy Custom setting will return a new Custom setting so it will not DNO. "If no custom setting data is defined for the user, this method returns a new custom setting object"

Comment: But the `Opened_Accounts_Url__c` on that record will be null. Indeed, if the setting itself were null, that would be a different error entirely.

Comment: Disregard. In my test I was setting `Pagereference(null)` which was different error (Ambiguous signature) from `String t; New pagereference(t);` in signatures. Should have replicated exactly....Latter does throw Arg 1 cannot be null

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thank you for your explanation, I added this code: ' External_Urls__c instance = External_Urls__c.getInstance(
        Opened_Accounts_Url__c='Populated'"
before my Test.StartTest(); and I'm getting an error message that the variable Opened_Accounts_Url__c doesn't exist. Could you tell me what I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: @Ghost fixed the syntax in my post.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ok, that part is working, now when I run the test I get a different error: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.
Class.OpenedAccountsTest.SandboxUrl: line 23, column 1

Comment: @Ghost that's a bit of a separate issue but you never initialize `org` to anything...it's still `null`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson True! I just did and it worked! 100% test coverage. You are the bomb! Where do I ship the keg?

Comment: Just pay it forward! Welcome to SFSE. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that the custom setting values for External_Urls__c has not been defined within this sandbox.  Please verify that this is a valid value.  If not you will need to create these values in your unit test to have the test pass successfully.

Comment: The custom setting exists and I created a button for it, it is calling a visualforce page and everything is working fine on the Sandbox, the problem is when I write the test classes.. I can't deploy it to prod. :(

Comment: When you say the custom setting exists you mean the value exists in salesforce but does not exist in your test execution due to test data isolation.  You are required to manually create this custom setting value in the context of your unit test.  That is why the test is failing..

Comment: Yes, I understood that after Adrian explained it. Thanks!